# Ошибка vk_api в python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я ввожу логин и пароль в Telegram-боте и и он должен авторизоваться, но он пишет ошибку:

**Ошибка авторизации: Unknown API auth error**

```
import telebot
import vk_api

telegram_token = '6820254210:AAEHrMM9GDIJmjdY16yUlQCXP9Wv3Q-Om4U'


bot = telebot.TeleBot(telegram_token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Для начала работы, введите ваш логин и пароль от ВКонтакте в формате: логин пароль.")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    # Проверяем, что введены логин и пароль
    if ' ' in message.text:
        # Получаем логин и пароль из сообщения
        login, password = message.text.split(' ')
        
        # Авторизуемся в ВКонтакте
        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password, app_id=2685278)
        try:
            vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Авторизация прошла успешно! Теперь вы можете отправлять сообщения.")
        except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ошибка авторизации: {error_msg}")
            return
        
        # Получаем экземпляр API
        vk = vk_session.get_api()
        
        # Отправляем сообщение во все чаты пользователя ВКонтакте
        try:
            vk.messages.send(message="Ваше сообщение здесь!", random_id=0)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Сообщение успешно отправлено во все чаты ВКонтакте.")
        except vk_api.ApiError as error_msg:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ошибка отправки сообщения: {error_msg}")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, введите логин и пароль от ВКонтакте в формате: логин пароль.")

# Запускаем бота в Telegram
bot.polling()
```